# Backwards compatibility in Android

Tags: android

I need to call a method in Android SDK v9 while maintaining compatibility with older versions.

The [Android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html) recommends using reflection or wrapper classes, but is that all really necessary? Why can't I just do this?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
    callNewMethod();
```

It seems to me this will work due to Java runtime linkage, since I am building with SDK 9. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That's exactly what I do, and it's been working fine for me all along. But that's just my $0.02, we'll see if someone can give a better answer than this...

Comment: Instead of using number 9 as API level, use Build.VERSIONS.XXX where xxx is the api version defined by google. just saying :D.

Comment: just guessing: since Java is a statically compiled language, each compile unit (a class in Java) has a list of dependencies to be resolved by the loader before running that unit's code.  If you use that callNewMethod(), your class might not load if there's no callNewMethod() at run time.

Comment: @AlexLockwood: of course, but when you run in an older system, there's no `callNewMethod()` but your class depends on it, so it would fail to be loaded, before it has a chance to check the runtime version.

Comment: disclaimer: i have no idea if this works or not, since i don't know if that method is defined in the libraries linked with your app and included in the `apk`, or if the loader links with the target OS libraries.  If the former, then it seems OK; if the latter, the class won't load.

Comment: For the record, I just tested this with an OS2.2 emulator and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not at all. Actually it is promoted as best approach while developing applications with wide API level target.

Reflection class is the most solid way, if you have no idea what the class content is and the method exist. But in Android, you know what is supported and what is not supported.

As a result, i didn't like the blog you gave :p

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a better answer, but the check you are doing there assumes that the builder of the OS/ROM set that value correctly.  If it was not set correctly, then you may try to access a method in SDK 9 that really isn't there.  Using reflection is the only way to be 100% sure you do not generate a runtime error by trying to call a non-existent method.